# Ria Applications - Desktop vs web feel

Tags: ria

I have seen web applications that have desktop look and feel (e.g those done with flex or extgwt) demo. I have also seen web applications (rich with ajax) that have web look and feel - e.g gmail . My questions is: which ones are more usable? and which ones are the future. I am not talking of websites here but applications, think accounting software or Human Resource management Software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is one thing you can bet on, I think, it would be HTML and JavaScript. Nothing is more ubiquitous. Moreover, with HTML5 it looks like you should be able to do almost anything that the other RIA frameworks provide.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is very general and it depends on allot of factors like:

- speed (those web looking tend to be faster)
- budget (those web looking are usually cheaper and quicker to implement)
- what the users expect, e.g. what they were used to before.
- company policy, branding, etc.

> | and which ones are the future

Well, if I could see the future ... :). Maybe both? :).

There are valid arguments in favor of both approaches, so it really depends from case to case what solution is the best.

Answer (score -1):

Javascript + HTML5 will be the future. [Ext](http://extjs.com), [CrossUI](http://www.crossui.com) ...

Comment: please explain more or mention this in comments